# How to mark up acceptable payment methods for a Schema.org Offer with Microdata?

Tags: html, microdata, schema.org

I am not sure how to markup accepted payment methods for an offer.

Here are the Schema.org types:

- [Offer](http://schema.org/Offer)
- [PaymentMethod](http://schema.org/PaymentMethod)

Here is my basic example, is this correct?

```html
<div itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/Product">
    <span itemprop="name">Product Name</span>

    <span itemprop="description">Product Description</span>

    <div itemprop="offers" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/Offer">
      <span itemprop="price">$19.95</span>
      <meta itemprop="priceCurrency" content="USD" />
      <meta itemprop="availability" content="in_stock" />
      <a href="/buy-now" itemprop="url">Buy Now</a>
      <meta itemprop="acceptedPaymentMethod" content="http://purl.org/goodrelations/v1#PayPal" />
      <meta itemprop="acceptedPaymentMethod" content=" http://purl.org/goodrelations/v1#PaymentMethodCreditCard" />
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Did you try this with rich snippets tool and see if the bot was able to correctly identify?

Comment: Yes I did, it pulls out a list of values. For example acceptedpaymentmethod:http://purl.org/goodrelations/v1#PayPal

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The basic direction is correct, but you must use `<link>` and `href=...` instead of `meta`, since the value is a URL/URI, not a string:

```
<link itemprop="acceptedPaymentMethod" href="http://purl.org/goodrelations/v1#PayPal" />
<link itemprop="acceptedPaymentMethod" href=" http://purl.org/goodrelations/v1#PaymentMethodCreditCard" />
```

The rest looks fine at first sight.

Answer (score 3):

About your HTML:

- You can (and should) use semantic markup, of course. So, for example, the product container should probably be an `article` instead of a `div`, and the "Product Name" should probably be an `h1` instead of `span`.
- Like [Martin Hepp writes](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/40997/17633) also, you have to use [`link` instead of `meta` if the value is a URI](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24659620/1591669).

About your Schema.org:

- The [`price` property](http://schema.org/price) should not contain the currency symbol.
- The [`availability` property](http://schema.org/availability) expects an [`ItemAvailability`](http://schema.org/ItemAvailability) enumeration value, which would be [`http://schema.org/InStock`](http://schema.org/InStock) in your case (used in a `link` element).
- Unless "`/buy-now`" is really a page for/about the `Offer`, you should probably not use `url` for it. If it’s a buy button, you could use [`BuyAction`](http://schema.org/BuyAction) instead.

So the example could look like:

```html
<article itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/Product">
  <h1 itemprop="name">Product Name</h1>

  <p itemprop="description">Product Description</p>

  <div itemprop="offers" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/Offer">
    $<span itemprop="price">19.95</span>
    <meta itemprop="priceCurrency" content="USD" />
    <link itemprop="availability" href="http://schema.org/InStock" />
    <div itemprop="potentialAction" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/BuyAction">
      <a itemprop="target" href="/buy-now">Buy Now</a>
    </div>
    <link itemprop="acceptedPaymentMethod" href="http://purl.org/goodrelations/v1#PayPal" />
    <link itemprop="acceptedPaymentMethod" href="http://purl.org/goodrelations/v1#PaymentMethodCreditCard" />
  </div>

</article>
```

Comment: How would he use the `BuyAction` schema in this example?

Comment: @Scott: In case you missed it, my example snippet contains `BuyAction`.